# Blob not found: Error when uploading tar.gz to Azure storage container using linux script

Tags: linux, backup, azure, tar

## Error

> The portal displays this `Blob not found.` error

[image]

> This is the XML error I get when I hit the `download` button

```
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>
        The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:bea21dfd-0001-004f-26e0-220af6000000 Time:2015-11-19T15:38:55.9836819Z
    </Message>
</Error>
```

## Background

I've been trying to implement a workaround for backing up my IaaS v2 Ubuntu VM in Azure. Thanks to an [excellent answer](https://serverfault.com/a/734362/316235) I received on Server Fault recently, I decided the best route would just be to periodically back up my server using tar and a cronjob.

So, I googled "tar backup on linux azure VM" - which brought me to [this article](https://jlark20.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/how-to-do-linux-backups-on-azure-without-shutting-the-vm-down/), namely: *How to do Linux backups on Azure without shutting the VM down*.

The tutorial outlines a process which **executes the tar command**, and then **uploads the tar to an azure storage container using the credentials listed**. Here is the script in question:

```
#!/bin/bash
# full system backup

# Backup destination
backdest=/opt/backup

# Labels for backup name
pc=${HOSTNAME}
distro=`uname -a | awk '{print $4}'` 
type=full
date=$(date "+%F")
backupfile="$backdest/$distro-$type-$date.tar.gz"
username=`whoami`

#blob storage variables
storageAccountName=storageaccountname
storageAccountKey=mylongassstoragekey
storageContainer=backupcontainername


# Exclude file location
prog=${0##*/} # Program name from filename
excdir=`pwd`
exclude_file="$excdir/$prog-exc.txt"


#check backup destination is there
if [ ! -d "$backdest" ]; then
        mkdir -p $backdest
fi

# Check if exclude file exists
if [ ! -f $exclude_file ]; then
  echo "checking exclude $exclude_file"
  echo -n "No exclude file exists, continue? (y/n): "
  read continue
  if [ $continue == "n" ]; then exit; fi
fi


#don't use nohup we want to make this blocking
tar --exclude-from=$exclude_file -czpvf $backupfile /

#after tar is finished move to blob storage
azure storage blob upload -a $storageAccountName --container $storageContainer -k $storageAccountKey $backupfile

echo "all done!"
```

Everything seems to go well, the script runs the backup, and then uploads the tar.gz as a block blob. But, as you can see from the above error, the Blob isn't found. The storage container is set to "Container" (as opposed to "Private").

I have no idea how to even start troubleshooting this. What do I do? Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. Couple things at fault here:

1. The script creates the blob with a filename starting with `$distro`, which happens to begin the filename with a `#`, which is a reserved URI character. I changed the script so that it resembled `$type_$date` instead.
2. The storage blob command was failing (silently) because the script wasn't running them with `sudo` priveleges. All I had to do was add `sudo` to both the `tar` and `azure storage` calls, and everything works!

Answer (score 1):

Blob names require you to escape reserved URL characters. Your blob name starts with a `#` which is a reserved URL character. I suspect the issue will resolve itself when you remove that character (or escape it). *Note: I haven't confirmed this with an independent test, but it's the first time I've ever seen a blob name with a `#` character...*

More info on blob naming [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135715.aspx).

Comment: That was definitely one of the issues David, thanks very much for your input. See my answer for full info :)